# Wordpress - how to insert a sticky image at left bottom corner

Tags: wordpress

How can i insert a sticky image to my wordpress site?
I want something like that: decomat.gr, there is an image at the very left bottom and is sticky.

Thank you.

i want this image to be sticky at the left bottom corner and be displayed at every page of my website.

Comment: You need to create sticky image in html,css first then add your html,css codes to your wordpress theme`s footer.

Answer (score 0):

The site you mention is built on Elementor. You could use a plugin or custom code like this to achieve what you want:

```css
*{padding:0;margin:0;}

body
{
  height: 1200px;
}

.float{
    position:fixed;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    bottom:0;
    left:40px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
}

.my-float{
    margin-top:22px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="float">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/1280px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png" style="max-width:100px"/>
</a>
```

You can then place this code where relevant to display across site.

Comment: Thank you! Where have to place this code?

Comment: CSS you can add in your CSS file 

The HTML part, you can add on Body opening tag?